# Callback URL for an app in Azure Directory

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

I need to add a custom scheme for callback url, something like `myapp://example.com/oauth/callback` to be able to redirect back to the app in ios and android devices, but I can't do that because it says invalid schema (it allows only `http://` and `https://`).

I do it there:

```
Azure Active Directory -> App registration -> app -> Reply URL
```

Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to create the reply url by

```
Azure Active Directory -> App registration -> app -> settings -> Reply URL
```

Navigate to

```
Azure Active Directory -> App registration -> app -> Manifest
```

This it the middle button next to settings. [image]

Once in there you will see the JSON representation of your app. Search for a section called

```
"replyUrls": [],
```

Add the reply url in there and press save at the top.

```
"replyUrls": [
    "myapp://example.com/oauth/callback"
],
```

Navigate back to

```
Azure Active Directory -> App registration -> app -> settings -> Reply URL
```

and validate the reply url has been set.

This should work as the client side code is doing the validation not the server side.

Hope this helps